# Any way to get my discord token from Browser Dev Console?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, google-chrome-devtools, developer-console

Is there any way to see my discord token in the dev console with any javascript code?

Comment: please don't ask us how to selfbot on discord.. it's against their tos

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that, I apologize for this question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sadly, the method posted by Scoooolzs stopped working after a recent webpack update.
Here's the new working code:

```js
(webpackChunkdiscord_app.push([[''],{},e=>{m=[];for(let c in e.c)m.push(e.c[c])}]),m).find(m=>m?.exports?.default?.getToken!==void 0).exports.default.getToken()
```

You can find a library in [this repo](https://github.com/gilgames000/discord-detours) to hook into Discord clients' functions.

(Community edit:)
Prettified:

```js
(
    webpackChunkdiscord_app.push(
        [
            [''],
            {},
            e => {
                m=[];
                for(let c in e.c)
                    m.push(e.c[c])
            }
        ]
    ),
    m
).find(
    m => m?.exports?.default?.getToken !== void 0
).exports.default.getToken()
```

Comment: Would someone care to explain how this code works? `m` seems to be defined within the body of an arrow function, yet is being 'emitted' via the `(foo, bar)` comma-operator to the filter-step. How is it not out of scope, when it is referenced for the second time?

Comment: Totally love the beautified version. Thanks @P i

Comment: How does this work?

Answer (score -2):

```js
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = localStorage.token;
```

Use this javascript in the browser console.